# How to solve $\beta = \alpha - \arcsin(k \cdot \sin(\alpha))$ for $\alpha$?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, angle

I'm looking for an analytical expression in the form of $\alpha = f (\beta)$, so solving the equation below for $\alpha$. Is this possible?

$$\beta = \alpha - \arcsin(k \cdot \sin(\alpha))$$

Comment: Since the equation is transcendental, only approximations. Is the problem in a range of $\alpha$ ? What are the bounds for $k$ and $\beta$ ? Clarify and show what you already tried.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That's not the case. This equation can be solved explicitly.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I was looking for some trigonometric relations in order to solve it explicitly, as jjagmath did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$\arcsin(k\cdot\sin \alpha) = \alpha - \beta $$
so $$k\cdot \sin \alpha =\sin(\alpha - \beta)  = \sin \alpha \cos\beta - \cos\alpha\sin\beta$$

Dividing by $\cos \alpha$ we get $$k\cdot \tan \alpha = \tan\alpha \cos\beta-\sin \beta$$

That is $$\tan\alpha = \frac{\sin\beta}{\cos\beta-k}$$
and finally $$\alpha =\arctan\left(\frac{\sin\beta}{\cos\beta-k}\right)$$

Since we are using inverse trigonometric functions this will be valid only on a certain interval and some adjustment will be necessary if one needs to extend the answer to a larger domain.